# Question on a subset $S$ of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ where for each $(x,y)\in S$ at least one of $x$ and $y$ is irrational

Tags: general-topology, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

If $S$ is a subset of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ such that one point of the ordered pair is rational and the other is irrational or both are irrationals. Then which of the following is true?

a) $S$ is closed

b) $S$ is open

c) $S$ is connected

d) $S$ is totally disconnected

e) $S$ is compact

Comment: You can get $\times$ with `\times`.

Comment: Hint: You need only to use the fact that both rational numbers and irrational numbers are dense in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS: It may be helpful to note that $S=[0,1]^2\setminus\Bbb Q^2$: $S$ is the set of points in the unit square that do **not** have both coordinates rational.

More specifically, answering (a) should give you the answer to (e) as well, and (a) and (b) should both be pretty easy to answer: does either $S$ or $[0,1]^2\setminus S$ contain a non-empty open ball? Answering either of (d) and (e) should give you the answer to the other. For (d) note that every horizontal line segment in $[0,1]^2$ whose $y$ coordinate is irrational lies completely in $S$, as does every vertical line segment whose $x$ coordinate is irrational.

Comment: So I was thinking that $S$ is neither closed (and therefore compact) nor open. By your line logic it is not totally disconnected, so that leaves that it is connected.

Comment: @NLawless: Those are all correct. It’s even path connected: from any point of $S$ you can get to any other point of $S$ via a path in $S$ consisting of one, two, or at most three of those line segments that I mentioned.