# Is $S$ connected in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Here is a question from the GRE Mock test.

Let $S$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ consisting of all points $(x, y)$ in the unit square $[0,1] \times[0,1]$ for which $x$ or $y$, or both, are irrational. With respect to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2}, S$ is

(A) closed

(B) open

(C) connected

(D) totally disconnected

(E) compact

This seems to be a rather famous question. It has been asked [Let $S \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ consisting of all points $(x,y)$ in the unit square $[0,1] × [0,1]$ for which $x$ or $y$, or both, are irrational.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3693465/let-s-subset-mathbbr2-consisting-of-all-points-x-y-in-the-unit-square), and [Question on a subset $S$ of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ where for each $(x,y)\in S$ at least one of $x$ and $y$ is irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525304/question-on-a-subset-s-of-0-1-times0-1-where-for-each-x-y-in-s-at-le). I'm having difficulty more with interpreting this question.

By "with respect to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2}, S$ is", does this mean that I should determine connectedness while taking open sets to be the open sets of the the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? Or should I consider connectedness as in the original definition, where I take the subspace topology induced by $S$?

Furthermore, if I took  open sets to be the open sets of the the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, would $S$ even be connected? Intuitively, I think not, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: The problem states you are to use the standard topology. For example, $S$ is not open in $\mathbb R^2$ but it is open in the subspace topology.

Comment: With regard to connectedness, the question of whether one is using the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ or the subspace topology comes down to definitions. A topological space $S$ is connected if it cannot be partitioned into two non-trivial open sets. This (of course) refers to the topology on $S$, which is the subspace  topology. It is so common though to consider connectedness of subspaces that some people (e.g. Munkres) write down a characterization of being connected in terms of open sets in the larger space.

Comment: $S$ is connected. Think of it as $[0,1]^2\backslash\mathbb Q^2$. Basically an infinitely fine grid. From any point within this set, you can move either up/down, or left/right, or both, without leaving the set. Use this to show path-connectedness.

Comment: Something similar happens with compactness. $S$ is compact if it's compact in the subspace topology. It's very common however to give a condition (in terms of the topology on, e.g., ${\mathbb{R}^2$) for a subspace to be compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, $S$ is not open, since $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$S$ is dense in $[0, 1]^2$. Since $S \neq [0, 1]^2$, clearly $S$ is not closed.

$S$ is connected - in fact, path-connected. Let $w = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Then there is a path from any point in $S$ to $(w, w)$. First, translate along the coordinate that is rational until that coordinate is $w$, if there is such a coordinate. Then, translate along the other coordinate.

Since $S$ is path-connected, it is clearly not totally disconnected.

Finally, since $S$ is not closed, it is not compact. This is because in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a subspace is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.